# How to transfer rows between two different Grids (Ag-grid Angular 6) using Drag and Drop?

Tags: angular, angular6, ag-grid

I want to transfer rows between two grids, having same column definition, One grid will hold the "free devices" and the other grid will hold the "devices to be added" , Is there a solution for this using drag and drop to transfer rows between two grids or any other way.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is in [ag-grid-pipeline](https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-pipeline/) and planned for `Next Release` as of now.

> *AG-1708: Row dragging: Allow dragging between grids or between the grid and a external element*

Comment: Thanks for answering , Is there any alternate way? Like using an external "Add"/"Remove" button.

Comment: You can manually do `rowData.slice` & `push` etc. onto the data bound to the grid if you anyways want to - but in that case it won't be actually `drag-drop`.

Answer (score 1):

There is now support for it with an example per your requirements:
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-drag-and-drop/#dragging-between-grids